# Finding the value of multiple input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a multiple quantity selector for my store. Image below:

[image]

On the site, the price of the product updates based on the quantity added. 10 products = 10% off etc. I'd like to be able to display this price change as and when the user edits any one of the input boxes in the quantity selector.

The input fields are built like this:

```
<div data-value="S" data-varientid="8195426353207" class="swatch-element swatch-element-2 size s available">

   <input id="swatch-0-s" data-variant-id="variant_8195426353207" type="checkbox" name="option-0" value="S">

   <label for="swatch-0-s">
                  S
      <img class="crossed-out" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0020/2188/3959/t/2/assets/soldout.png?5180939831627851747" alt="">
   </label>

   <input id="qty" name="quantity" class="swatchinput" placeholder="0" value="0" type="text">

</div>
```

I'm able to watch the input boxes for change by doing the below:

```
  var qty = $('.swatchinput');

  $('.swatchinput').on('paste keyup', function() {
    console.log(qty);
  });
```

However, this returns the information about the element rather than the contents. I'm also unsure of the best way to then add the contents of the various input fields together to reach the total quantity.

Comment: Give us the HTML

Comment: So that loop over all the elements and add them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the Array reduce method to do this.  Select all the inputs, get the array, then reduce their values into the sum.

```js
var total = $('.swatchinput').get().reduce(function(total, input){
  return total + parseInt(input.value || '0');
}, 0);

console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="quantity" class="swatchinput" placeholder="0" value="1" type="text">
<input name="quantity" class="swatchinput" placeholder="0" value="2" type="text">
<input name="quantity" class="swatchinput" placeholder="0" value="3" type="text">
<input name="quantity" class="swatchinput" placeholder="0" value="4" type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used this method as it made the most sense to me - but I'm sure the other answers work too.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be

```
 var qty = $('.swatchinput').val();
```

not

```
var qty = $('.swatchinput');
```

As for your second question,

loop each of these inputs, getting the value, then add them up with a total. Initialize the total OUTSIDE of the loop also so it doesn't overwrite it.

Comment: highly doubt that is what the OP wants

Comment: The OP is getting the element when console.logging, so yes, they stated they wanted the value. Did you read their post?

Comment: Yes I read the post and they want to add up all of the input values to get the total quantity.

Comment: Yes, and as I said. The first issue is that they're getting the element, not the value of it.  Then I said loop each input and add them together. The original question was the issue of getting the element info and not the value within.

Comment: And them adding val() outside is going to be the value when it was loaded, not what was changed. So that is still an issue. And when I made the comment, you did NOT have the last blurb. Made comment 4 minutes ago and you edited 3 minutes ago with that last chunk.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var total = 0;

$('.switchinput').each(function(){
    total += $(this).val();
});

console.log(total);
```

To get the value of an element in jQuery, use .val():

http://api.jquery.com/val/

.each loops through each matched element and runs a function on that element (accessible through 'this')

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Nice answer.  I'd suggest you add some explanation / comments.  Code-only answers aren't as useful... :)